# Connecting to Mysql without using tcp

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I have a wierd question from my Client but need some technical details to justify his madness. Is it possible to connect to a mysql server which is on the same server as the application server i.e tomcat to connect without tcp. We are using jdbc and mysql driver to connect to the database from the application. Can anyone help me to draft some details or make me understand if am missing any.

Thanks,
Sirish.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `--protocol` and select one of `{TCP|SOCKET|PIPE|MEMORY}`.  See the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connecting.html

Comment: Thank you Alian. DO you know which one is the best by chance..?? We are currently running over linux and see we can use TCP or Scoket as per the documentation. Will sockets be a good idea.?

Comment: No personal experience, but I did find [this old link](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/179624) that claims:  From the Connector/J documentation:

"Named pipes only work when connecting to a MySQL server on the same 
physical machine as the one the JDBC driver is being used on. In simple 
performance tests, it appears that named pipe access is between 30%-50% 
faster than the standard TCP/IP access."